# How can I rewrite all signal names to a shorter name?

Tags: foreach, tcl, modelsim, waveform, questasim

I'm using QuestaSim/ModelSim and I would like to automatically rewrite the signal names displayed in the waveform. When my testbench starts, a default command loads all top-level signals into the waveform viewer:

```
add wave testharness/*
```

When I rename the added signals, the following commands are created in a waveform save file (*.wdo):

```
add wave -noupdate -label SerialClock_Wire /iic_controller_tb/testharness/SerialClock_Wire
```

So a label with a shorter name can be applied to each signal.

I would like to iterate all top-level signals or signals in a given hierarchy and add them to the waveform, while shortening their names (removing the path prefix).

How can I do such iteration and name shortening?

Comment: Wouldn't just displaying the signal name help, without the hierarchy. Would `config wave -signalnamewidth 1` work? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804835/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-leaf-names-in-modelsim-through-the-tcl-api) answer out.
If not it's TCL, so you need to able to query the simulation database for a list of signals at a particular node and tinker around with strings.

Comment: Try using this (there may be better _TCL_ ways)

`set sigs [find signals {-internal} sim:/mytestbench/mytop/myblock/*]

foreach a $sigs {

    # do something with $a

}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bottom left corner of the wave window in `ModelSim`, there is a tiny icon that looks like a seashell.
Clicking it toggles between the full names and the leaf names, which is exactly the functionality you are referring to.